# Div moves across the screen instead of stopping at specified point

Tags: jquery, html

I need to make the `div` move from its initial position to the new position using jQuery but once the div is interacted with, it scrolls across the entire page. I just want the div to move from point A to point B and stop at point B.

```
var main=function() {

$('.sun').animate({

left:'10px'

},800);

}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/55aLmvn5/1/

```
.sun {
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;

}
```

This is what I am using for CSS to make sure the div does not extend to 100%. I think your div is just the standard block level size hence the scrolling.

Comment: .sun
{
 background-color:#FFA93B;
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 position:absolute;
 border-radius:50px;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 
 box-shadow:0px 0px 40px #FFCE90;
 
 }
This is my css and still the div seems to move to the end of the screen

Comment: Thanks figured it out. Is there a way to trace a the path of the div like making it move in a fixed path.

Comment: @RakeshRenzous - you'll probably need a plugin for that, unless you're good with math.  jquery.path may be a good start for you - https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path

Comment: @RakeshRenzous That is complicated although a quick and dirty solution can be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/55aLmvn5/2/

Comment: @JSess I am so sorry i really new to this.Can you send me a jsfiddle example on that ?

Comment: No problem - Using the plugin from the link I provided above (jquery.path), here is an example usage from their documentation. http://jsfiddle.net/jmsessink/uucyhwgn/.  They have the different types of paths listed on the github link - http://github.com/weepy/jquery.path, and their demo is here - http://weepy.github.io/jquery.path/